# Why does perf stat -a --topdown silently fail with no percentages?

Tags: perf

```
% perf stat -a --topdown -- dd if=/dev/urandom count=10 > /dev/null
Using CPUID GenuineIntel-6-5E-3
topdown-total-slots -> cpu/event=0x3c,umask=0,any=0x1/
topdown-slots-retired -> cpu/event=0xc2,umask=0x2/
topdown-recovery-bubbles -> cpu/event=0xd,umask=0x1,cmask=0x1,any=0x1/
topdown-fetch-bubbles -> cpu/event=0x9c,umask=0x1/
topdown-slots-issued -> cpu/event=0xe,umask=0x1/
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
5120 bytes (5.1 kB, 5.0 KiB) copied, 6.1006e-05 s, 83.9 MB/s

 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

                                    retiring      bad speculation       frontend bound        backend bound 
S0-D0-C0           1                                                                                                          
S0-D0-C1           1                                                                                                          
S0-D0-C2           1                                                                                                          
S0-D0-C3           1                                                                                                          

       0.002117518 seconds time elapsed
```

I get no output for this or any other command run under `perf stat -a --topdown`, but I don't see any error messages either. To be specific, I see the above output, but it's missing any percentages for the 4 categories.

Comment: Is it possible that `perf` mixes output to its stderr and stdout, so your redirect discarded part of it?  Try timing something that you *don't* need to redirect to /dev/null, e.g. `dd if=... of=/dev/null`

Comment: I got the same thing with running `ls`, I just didn't want to mix in that output.